How to hide not wanted SSL information in output from openssl
Using this command:
printf Q | openssl s_client -verify_quiet -servername 192.168.0.1 -connect 192.168.0.1:443 | openssl x509 -checkend 864000 -noout -enddate

I am getting this output:
depth=1 CN = System Manager CA, OU = MGMT, O = ORG
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
DONE
notAfter=Nov  9 23:03:07 2024 GMT
Certificate will not expire

I am unable to hide this part.
depth=1 CN = System Manager CA, OU = MGMT, O = ORG
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
DONE

I am able to hide it by a text operations after parsing the result. But I wanted to take it simply by main command. Any advice?

This is not a programming or development issue and is out of scope, but: those 3 lines are output on stderr and can be suppressed by redirecting 2>/dev/ null (on Unix; on Windows use NUL:). Alternatively you can use 2>&1 to 'merge' them to the pipe, or in some shells just use |& which does this for you, and the openssl x509 process will discard them. And BTW putting an IPaddress in SNI violates the RFCs.

Thank you @dave_thompson_085, this helped.
